# Wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to retrieve page contents with an `AJAX` call.  I have a series of links within a page wrapper.  When I click on a link, it loads a JavaScript function that retrieves page contents from a `php` script.  In this case I am developing on my `localhost`, but in production the script will be within the same root folder and domain as the file that does the `AJAX` call.  I am using the response as the content for a `div`.  The content isn't purely `PHP`, and by that I mean while it is generated by php it has `HTML` elements like `div`s and spans.  It's basically the stuff that is going between the opening and closing body tags.  Because of this, I'm not sure I can just use `json_encode`.

Instead of the content loading in the `div`, I get the following error:

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: http:// wrapper is
>   disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

After reading up on `allow_url_include` it seems that this is usually disabled by default.  I'm assuming that this feature allows for some serious site attacks.  Is that the case.   If so, how can I retrieve the content from another file?

I tried using the `JQuery` load function:

```
$('#content').load('pages/test_page.php');
```

but with the exact same results.

This is driving me nuts!  TIA.

**EDIT:**  I think I may have found the problem; the `php` file that the `AJAX` is retrieving content from is using `require_once`.  The file that it is requiring is on the same server within the same root folder, but it was one directory up.  HOWEVER, that creates a new problem:  I'm getting the content, but not fully.  For example, in the file I have this:

```
Title:  <?php echo $details['title']; ?>
```

I am only getting the first letter, and this holds true for other `php` content that I `echo`.

Answer (score 10):

`allow_url_include` only affects `include()` and `require()`, you can still use the PEAR `HTTP_Request2` module or the `curl` functions to fetch webpages.

Using `include()` for remote webpages is considered to be a "bad practice", and may pose a security risk. For example, if you use `include($var);` and some attacker manages to replace $var with `http://hacksite.tld` he/she can "inject" code ...

Answer (score 1):

No worries, just use `file_get_contents()` then write a new file in your documents with the contents you have retrieved, then `include` the file in your file. the file you included now is ready for any change you want, using `css` ,`javascript`, etc.. this is basically what a wrapper does.

Answer (score -2):

that is because you are using a full url.
try the following instead:

```
$('#content').load('test_page.php');
```